# Sproutcore install - Could not find RubyGem

Tags: rubygems, sproutcore

I install the sproutcore gem by doing the following:

```
$ sudo gem install sproutcore --pre
Fetching: haml-3.1.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: sass-3.1.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: fssm-0.2.7.gem (100%)
Fetching: compass-0.11.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: thin-1.2.11.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Fetching: sproutcore-1.6.0.rc.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed haml-3.1.1
Successfully installed sass-3.1.1
Successfully installed fssm-0.2.7
Successfully installed compass-0.11.1
Successfully installed thin-1.2.11
Successfully installed sproutcore-1.6.0.rc.2
```

But when I try to run `sc-init` I get the following errors:

```
$ sc-init sc-microblog
/Users/joris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:926:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem sproutcore (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
        from /Users/joris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:244:in `activate_dep'
        from /Users/joris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:236:in `activate'
        from /Users/joris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1307:in `gem'
        from /Users/joris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/sc-init:18:in `<main>'
```

It doesn't seem to find the sproutcore gem it just installed.. for some reason. However:

```
$ which sproutcore
/Users/joris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/sproutcore
```

Google doesn't seem to know an answer to this, nor did the Sproutcore website. I *could* install using one of the installers, but I'd rather just go through RubyGems and figure this error message out. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by running

`gem update --system`

and installing sproutcore again:

`sudo gem install sproutcore --pre`

Not sure why this works now, but I guess I just needed to update..